# Convergence radius and is a series convergent in the ends of that radius

Tags: analysis

Find the convergence radius of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^{1/3}(5x)^n$$

I find that the convergence radius is $1/5$, but how does one check if the series is convergent at both ends of the interval (as far as i can see D'Alambert's method does not work) for the given example?  What should one know about the comparison principles? And how suitable is the use of definite integrals in proving convergence?

Comment: Do you mean the $1/3$ power to apply to the $(2n-1)!!$ as well?  Otherwise the radius of convergence would be $0$.

Comment: yes (2n-1)!!^(1/3)

Comment: @Guest25 Interesting question.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

First, we have the identities

$$(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!} \tag 1$$

and

$$(2n)!!=2^n\,n! \tag 2$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ shows that

$$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n\,(n!)^2} \tag 3$$

Next, we use Stirlings approximation $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$ in $(3)$ to reveal that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^{1/3}\sim (\pi n)^{-1/6}} \tag 4$$

Thus, at the endpoints of the interval of convergence, the terms of the series are or order $n^{-1/6}$, from which we conclude that the series converges at $x=-1/5$ and diverges at $x=+1/5$.